# Exchange OnLine / Office 365 / OWA - Cannot see PDF previews and cannot download attachments

Tags: microsoft-office-365, outlook-web-app, exchangeonline

This is a problem from a customer. When he opens an email with a PDF attachment in OWA, the mail opens with no problems, but clicking on the attachment will show an error or a white box.

[image: white preview box]

Clicking the download button for the PDF, a page with this message appears:

```
   Your mailbox isn't available right now. Please wait 30 seconds and then try to access it again.
```

Clearing the cache doesn't work. Other accounts are working on the same pc/browser.

Answer (score 0):

That was a little tricky.

After a few hours searching, found an hit that allowed me to go in the right direction and I found the cause of the problem.

This user is configured in this way:

**Username**: jeanluc@enterprise.com

**Mail address**: j.picard@enterprise.com

there was another user, WITH NO Office365/EOL license, with

**Username**: j.picard@enterprise.com

**Mail address**: < empty >

deleting the 2nd user solved the problem.

Comment: Oh,I am glad to know this issue is resolved by yourself. You could mark the helpful replies as answers, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well.

Comment: yes, I wrote it here after losing a few hours searching for the solution, for everyone sake ;) !
I cannot upvote or accept my own answer